# javascript: how to modify the query string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Like

```
?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

I only want to change b=6 while keep the other things the same, how to do it?

Comment: Do you want to change URL variable??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here a small function to do this:

```
jQuery.replaceURLParam = function (oldURL, replaceParam, newVal) {
var iStart = oldURL .indexOf(replaceParam  + '=');
var iEnd = oldURL .substring(iStart + 1).indexOf('&');
var sEnd = oldURL .substring(iStart + iEnd + 1);
var sStart = oldURL .substring(0, iStart);

var newURl = sStart + replaceParam + '=' + newVal;

if (iEnd > 0) {
    newURl += sEnd;
}

return newURl;
```

}

document.body.innerHTML = jQuery.replaceURLParam('www.foo.com?a=1&b=2&c=3', 'b', 6) ;

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3rkrn/

Answer (score 2):

Following function if you have to replace any b=XXX with b=newBValue

```
function ReplaceB(strQuery,newBValue)
{
var idxStart= strQuery.indexOf("b=")
if(idxStart<0)
 return; // b= not found, nothing to change
var idxFin=strQuery.substr(0,idxStart).indexOf("&");
var newQuery;
if(idxFin<0)
newQuery = strQuery.substr(0,idxStart) + "b="+newBValue
 else
newQuery = strQuery.substr(0,idxStart) + "b="+newBValue+strQuery.substr(idxStart+idxFin)
return newQuery;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = "?a=1&b=2&c=3".replace(/b=2/gi,"b=6");
alert(test);
```

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Shaz/v2vSR/1/)

```
var test = "?a=1&b=2&c=3".replace("b=2","b=6");
alert(test);
```

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Shaz/v2vSR/3/)

```
var test = "?a=1&b=2&c=3".split("b=2").join("b=6");
alert(test);
```

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Shaz/v2vSR/2/)

### Regardless of Number

Want to change to value of b regardless of number it is already? Use:

```
var test = "?a=1&b=2&c=3".replace(/b=\d/gi, "b=6");
alert(test);
```

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Shaz/uXjZY/)

Comment: @alex Why is that? Edit: Ah yes, I see what you mean now; post changed. :P

Comment: Only 'cos I guess it looks better, or something :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var queryStr = "?a=1&b=2&c=3";
var startTag = "b=";
var endTag = "&";
var index1 = queryStr.indexOf(startTag) + startTag.length;
var index2 = queryStr.indexOf(endTag,index1);
var newValue = 23;
queryStr = queryStr.substr(0, index1) +   newValue + queryStr.substr(index2);
alert(queryStr);
```

See it here : http://jsfiddle.net/aQL8p/

Answer (score 1):

```
var queryString = '?a=1&b=2&c=3'.replace(/([?&;])b=2([$&;])/g, '$1b=6$2');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3AUkZ/).

(JavaScript regex does not support lookbehinds).

Comment: "JavaScript regex does not support lookbehinds" : Should of seen me going from as3 to javascript. I was going crazy wondering why my regex wasn't working correctly!

Comment: @Shaz Sounds like fun. You'll also notice I didn't use a positive lookahead. No reason why, maybe symmetry? :P

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you - a more or less universal urlFor:

https://gist.github.com/4108452

You would simply do

```
newUrl = urlFor(oldUrl, {b:6});
```